# Stop whole page from sliding down when new answers have been posted

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

Sometimes, I use Stack Overflow from a laptop with small screen real estate. I find it annoying that the notification that appears at the top of the screen "pushes" all other content down on the page to show itself, especially when I'm typing out an answer still.

It would be nice if it incorporated a `position:fixed` as to keep from pushing the contents on the page down. I understand that it would potentially cover up the top bar, but it can easily be hidden by clicking the 'X' and that would be far less annoying to me that having everything on the page moving to show it.